# Finding missing integers from multiplicative group mod 56

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

From Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra (5ed), end of Chapter 2:

The integers 5 and 15 are among a collection of 12 integers that form a group under multiplication mod 56. List all 12.

I'm having trouble with this because firstly, I calculated $\phi(56) = 24$. So, a multiplicative group mod 56 should have 24 elements, no? The elements relatively prime to 56 would form a multiplicative group. But this question says 12 elements would work.

What am I missing? How can there be such a 12 element group?

Comment: A group of order $24$ can have a subgroup of order $12$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may need an answer like this:

The group includes $5$, since this is a group under multiplication modulo $56$, it has $1,5,25,13,9,45$.

Secondly, the group contains $15$ and $15$ is not in those six numbers, so the group consist of $15$ times each of $1,5,25,13,9,45$, that is, $15,19,39,27,23,3$.

And for the question "why can there be such a 12-element group", it is because the multiplication under modulo $56$ is an abelian group, thus it can be written as a direct sum of cycles. Some cycle will be even, thus if we take half of that cycle and other cycles, there will be a $12$-element subgroups.

I hope this helps.